# How to plot columns numbered greater than 1000 in gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have a file with 1600 columns.

```
plot "file" using 1:999 title columnhead(999)
```

plots column 999, but

```
plot "file" using 1:1000 title columnhead(1000)
```

produces column 100 instead of 1000, producing the same result as

```
plot "file" using 1:100 title columnhead(100)
```

Apparently large column numbers are wrapped. Is there a work-around so that I can plot larger column numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is a bug, see [#1596 columnhead(x) does not work for x>=1000](http://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1596/).

As workaround you can extract the first line e.g. with the command line tool `head`, and access the content with `word`:

```
header = system('head -n 1 file')
plot 'file' using 1:1000 skip 1 title word(header, 1000)
```